# TypeScript subset multiple elements of a tuple

Tags: typescript

Is there any way in TypeScript to subset a tuple and get the *ith and (i - 1)th* element?

I.e. something like:

```
type A = [string, number, symbol, boolean];
type B<T extends any[], U extends keyof T> = [T[U - 1], T[U]] // Here T[U - 1] is not valid TS ofc;

type C = B<A, 2> // [number, symbol];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest approach here without needing recursion would be to recognize that for a tuple `T`, the `U-1`th element of `T` is the same as the `U`th element of `[undefined, ...T]`, using a [variadic tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types) to prepend `undefined` to the tuple `T`.  That use of `undefined` is somewhat subjective; I picked it because generally speaking `arr[-1]` is going to give you `undefined`.  But it depends on your use case what the right thing to do there is.

Conceptually then you'd want to write

```
type B<T extends any[], U extends keyof T> =
    [[undefined, ...T][U], T[U]];
```

But the type checker doesn't understand that `U` is definitely an index of `[undefined, ...T]` for generic `T`.  It can't perform the higher-order reasoning that says "a longer tuple has all the indices of a shorter tuple".  So we have to convince it to allow the indexing somehow.  One way is to introduce a [conditional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) check that performs the index if the key is known to be present:

```
type Idx<T, K> = K extends keyof T ? T[K] : never;
```

And that gives you:

```
type B<T extends any[], U extends keyof T> =
    [Idx<[undefined, ...T], U>, T[U]];
```

Let's test it out:

```
type A = [string, number, symbol, boolean];
type C = B<A, 2> // [number, symbol];
type Q = B<A, 0> // [undefined, string]
type R = B<A, 100>; // [undefined, undefined]
```

Looks good.  Again, it depends on your use case what you want to see happen when the index is out of bounds or at the edges. But hopefully you can tweak it to suit your needs.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FDAuE8AcFMAICEA8AVW0AepoDsAmBnWAQ23AG0BdAGlgFU1McDYBracAewDNZkA+WAF5gsUbDIBJXOkRkArnmhcAltmi4aAOm3JqdPjWRlaFCgG4QEGLCkzkNANIDBsBwyx5CbTj1QB+XjIHClgALlg1ADdoACcLMCg4AEEhcXxQGNUAcxpsOQBbACNYmnxwIo4AGxpCjiroEnME6wBhVKQkmgAmAQB6XvE8opLYMorKpqs4AEV2xE7YAAY+gflFFTUNUYzsima4ACU5hYBGReWzWH7xBVwlVXUaW-vNvaA)

Answer (score 2):

Well, it's possible, if you find a way to do basic arithmetic in the TypeScript type system. I got my inspiration and the utility types from [this Medium article](https://itnext.io/implementing-arithmetic-within-typescripts-type-system-a1ef140a6f6f):

```
type Length<T extends any[]> = T extends { length: infer L } ? L : never;

type Tuple<L extends number, T extends any[] = []> = 
    T extends { length: L } ? T : Tuple<L, [...T, any]>;

type MinusOne<X extends number> =
    Tuple<X> extends [...(infer U), any] ? Length<U> : never;

type A = [string, number, symbol, boolean];

type B<T extends any[], U extends number & keyof T> = [T[MinusOne<U>], T[U]];

type C = B<A, 2>;
```

<sup>[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=12&ssc=19&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAMhB2BzYALAPAFShAHsBAJgM5QCG8IA2gLoB8UAvFFrvvMVAN5QA2CyKAFxQAlvABmEAE6woAXygB+WcPgQAbtIDcAKB2hIzAK5g+aGNjyES8IwFsARtIA0zS2w7kq1RlBr0mHShgt1ZrLl5+VGELBWUsYQwTMxhXSgA6TIxXLzpdfXBoAFkxIyIAeTU0AA13cNtHaQDjUwga+jD2EgzMgAoxSRkAVQBKHIofZTgkVDQh+lUNbT0DaABBX0oiYCkxRFcGpylXIhBHAHseVwdzy4hyanzVqAAhTDqusgoaVyGPjkO0igADIoABrCAgc7iZjNSgYSglWwVKrzaiuBFDaiPFaFKAAYV8bzWrgATLQtFAgA)</sup>

---

The solution relies on the fact that you can build tuple types of any length with a recursive approach (the `Tuple` type), and that you can infer the length of a tuple (the `Length` type) because arrays have a `length` property. Then it's just a matter of using those two together to create a decremented number type (the `MinusOne` type).

Answer (score 0):

You *can* do math in TypeScript types using [recursive](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#example/recursive-type-references) [conditional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) types but not with operators (e. g. `-`) as you demonstrated.

If you're only working with a few items and don't seek for a dynamic solution you could `infer` these specific tuple items and build a new tuple type.

```
type A = [string, number, symbol, boolean];
type B<T extends any[]> = T extends [...any, infer U, infer V, any]
  ? [U, V]
  : never;

type C = B<A>; // [number, symbol];
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDaBnYAnAlgOwOYBopsBXAWwCMJ1CUQKB7AG0PPqYgENsBdAbgChQkKACEAPABUoEAB7AI2ACYooXEEm4A+BFCmz5SlUgB0ptYRwAzKlACqF7NfRQAaoTXd+UKAH5k9109vAC4iCAA3KgFBcGgAYR1xGE1eKAB6NOQSCioaOlZGPn4gA)